# Is direct initialization forbidden for array?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer

Language-lawyer-wise, which clause in the standard forbid below code:

```
int arr[] (10, 42);
```

This would produce an array of 10 elements, each initalized to 42.

Comment: `int arr[10]; std::fill_n(arr, 10, 42);`

Comment: The best you're going to get with actual initialization for a built-in array is probably `int arr_0[] = {MAGIC_REPEAT_MACRO(10, 42)};`. IIRC, `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` will allow that. The dupe really doesn't cover initialization in C++ AFAICT.

Comment: Use `constexpr`, be happy :).  Write a `constexpr` function that builds the array, call it from the initializer.

Comment: @user3791991: Why would you think that `(10, 42)` means "produce 10 elements, each initialized to 42"?  No compiler would ever treat the first value as a count and the next value as an initializer. `std::vector` has a constructor that accepts such values, eg `std::vector<int> arr(10, 42);`, but a plain ordinary array does not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, If the hypothetical cause is "lack of constructor" for those built-in types, then why would `int num(10);`  work? That too appears like a constructor call.

Comment: @user3791991: That is value-initializing a single variable, not an array of values.  The language produces for such syntax in value initialization. There is no such syntax for initializing an array, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I agreed that "non-class type" is the cause based after delved into Falias's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language-lawyer wise, 8.5/17:

> — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>
> — If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.5.3.
>
> — If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of char16_t, an array of char32_t, or an
>   array of wchar_t, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2.
>
> — If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.
>
> — Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed

A braced-init-list is { } where anything (or nothing) can be inside the brackets (for example, `int arr[3] = {1,2,3}`).  With that in mind, none of the first 4 options are viable for `int arr[] (10, 42);`, leaving the last one indicating the program is ill-formed.

Comment: In the 4th case, does `()` mean no expression can be inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @user3791991 That's correct, though its worth noting that whitespace can be inside the parens

Comment: @Falias, then, Why below statement init the destination type to **1** (verified)? `int num();`

Comment: @user3791991 That gets parsed as a function declaration, there's no initialization involved.

Answer (score 0):

8.5/14:

> If the entity being initialized does not have class type, the *expression-list* in a parenthesized initializer shall be a single expression.

Comment: I don't think that applies to `int arr[](expression);` which is not permitted anyway?