# C++ allocate and construct objects in array with parameters

Tags: c++, new-operator

From here [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5b%5d/), it is unclear to me is it possible to allocate and construct objects with parameters. Like this:

```
struct MyClass {
  int data;
  MyClass(int k) {} 
};

int main () {
  // allocates and constructs five objects:
  MyClass * p1 = new MyClass[5](1);               // allocate 5 objects, and init all with '1'
}
```

Which is not work...

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500164/is-direct-initialization-forbidden-for-array

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't work, but you can use an `std::vector<MyClass>` for that:

```
std::vector<MyClass> p1(5, 1);
```

This will create a vector containing 5 `MyClass` objects. Note that this works because your single parameter constructor is not `explicit`. If it were, you would need

```
std::vector<MyClass> p1(5, MyClass(1));
```

Comment: But it construct it one, by one? I don't need vector.

Comment: @tower120 Yes, just like when you instantiate an array.

Comment: I have to do this `MyClass * p3 = static_cast<MyClass*> (::operator new (sizeof(MyClass[5])));` And than call constructor explicitly for each object?

Comment: @tower120 No, you do what I told you to do in my answer.

Comment: I have pool object implementation that use C native arrays. I create bunch of objects at once. Now I want to create initialized objects.

Comment: @tower120 I am not sure how you create a bunch of objects "at once", but you may want to look at [*placement new*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote does not work, but you could do this since C++11.
Still, better avoid dynamic allocation and go for automatic object.
Also, most times you really should use a standard container like `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
MyClass * a = new MyClass[5]{1,1,1,1,1};
MyClass b[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
std::vector<MyClass> c(5, 1);
std::vector<MyClass> d(5, MyClass(1));
std::array<MyClass,5> e{1,1,1,1,1};
```

Comment: Looks good, but what about variable number of instances and per object arguments? :)

Comment: @tower: In that case, hope you can default-construct them. Or it won't work at all.

Comment: Well, lets consider we don't have default constructor. Than I have to iterate each constructor. Right?